# Diagram of an Acoustic Doppler Current Profiler (ADCP) in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to write a report on some equipment that I used during some analysis, the diagram is shown below:

[image]

I attempt to re-create this with `tikz`, here is my attempt so far

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% draw main body
\fill[gray!40!black!20](0,0) rectangle (5cm,7.5cm);
% draw bottom
\fill[red!80!black!70](0,0) rectangle (5cm,2cm);
% draw top
\draw[fill = blue](0,6) rectangle (5cm,7.5cm);
% draw circles at top of diagram
\fill[cyan!70!white](1.5,7)circle(0.5cm);
\fill[cyan!70!white](3.5,7)circle(0.5cm);
% draw lines 
\draw (1,7.5)--(0.5,9);
\draw (2,7.5)--(2.5,9);

\draw (3,7.5)--(2.5,9);
\draw (4,7.5)--(4.5,9);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

resulting in:

[image]

which to be fair is terrible. I am struggling to find a way of (1) generating the top of the diagram i.e. the top bit and make it seem that the beams are traveling away from the source. How would I do this?

Also, I realize that I'll have to play around with this a lot to make it look anywhere near the original diagram, but I thought I'd start by getting the main details in order. Can anyone suggest any way of making my attempt look a bit closer to the diagram, keeping in mind that my `tikz` skills are very limited.

Comment: I suggest you to use *Inkscape* to draw it and export as `pdf` image.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This type of diagram may be more efficiently drawn in Inkscape and the likes but, with a little bit of patience, is totally within the remit of TikZ.

To convey that the beams are traveling away from the source, I suggest using a `shade`, like below. The code is far from optimal, especially in terms of maintainability, but the important bits are there. Feel free to improve it.

[image: output screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
        % grey metallic part
        \def\xgrey{1.2}
        \def\ygrey{0}
        \def\hgrey{1}
    \shadedraw[%
        draw                = black,%
        left color  = gray!20,%
        right color = gray!90,%
        rounded corners = 1,
    ] (-\xgrey,\ygrey) rectangle (\xgrey,{\ygrey+\hgrey});

    % red part
    \def\yred{-.5}
    \def\hred{.5}
    \shadedraw[%
        draw                = black,%
        left color  = red!20,%
        right color = red!90,%
        rounded corners = 1,
    ] (-\xgrey,\yred) rectangle (\xgrey,{\yred+\hred});
    \def\yred{-.5}
    \def\hred{.5}
    \def\redratio{1.1}
    \shade[%
        left color  = blue!20,%
        right color = blue!90,%
        opacity=.2,
        rounded corners = 1,
    ] (-\xgrey,\yred) rectangle (\xgrey,{\yred+\hred});
    \draw [rounded corners = 1,
    ] (-{\redratio*\xgrey},\yred) rectangle ({\redratio*\xgrey},{\yred+\hred});

    % blue part
    \begin{scope}[scale=1.8,shift={(0,1)}]
        \shadedraw[%
            left color  = blue!20,%
            right color = blue!90,%
            rounded corners=3,
        ]    (-.11,0)
            -- (.11,0)
            -- (.76,-.2)
            -- (.78,-.53)
            -- (-.78,-.53)
            -- (-.76,-.2)
            -- cycle;
        \draw[rounded corners=1] (-.78,-.53) rectangle (.78,-.58);
        \shadedraw[%
            left color  = blue!20,%
            right color = blue!90,%
            rounded corners=1,
        ] (-.11,0) -- (.11,0) -- (.11,.-.53) -- (-.11,.-.53) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}

    % ellipses and beams
    \def\rayyangle{15}
    \def\yray{3}
    \def\hray{4}
    \def\a{.4}
    \def\b{.1}
    \def\afactor{1.2}
    \def\bfactor{1.5}
    \newcommand\stuffray[1]{
        \draw[rotate={#1},fill=gray!90,thin]  ellipse ({\a*\afactor} and {\b*\bfactor});
        \draw[rotate={#1},fill=gray!20,thin]  ellipse ({\a} and {\b});
        \path[%
            rotate={#1},
            shade,%
            bottom color = gray!20,%
            top color = gray!1,%
            opacity=.5,
        ]    (-\a,0)
            -- (-\a,{\hray})
            -- (\a,{\hray})
            -- (\a,0)
            -- cycle;
        \draw[black,very thin,rotate={#1},opacity=.1] (-\a,0) -- (-\a,{\hray});
        \draw[black,very thin,rotate={#1},opacity=.1] (\a,0) -- (\a,{\hray});
    }

    \def\xrayshift{.72}
    \def\yrayshift{1.45}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(-\xrayshift,\yrayshift)}]
        \stuffray{\rayyangle}
    \end{scope}
     \begin{scope}[shift={(\xrayshift,\yrayshift)}]
            \stuffray{-\rayyangle}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is awesome.

Answer (score 6):

This might be a start, but, as said above in the comments, I think drawing this with e.g. Inkscape might be more efficient.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\def\beamr{0.5}
\def\beamlen{3}
\def\width{2.3}
\def\topwidth{3}
\def\toptopwidth{0.5}
\def\topheighta{0.8}
\def\topheightb{1.0}
\def\midwidth{0.4}

\newcommand\drawbeam{
  \draw[draw=black!75, fill=black, fill opacity=0.2] 
       (-\beamr, 0) -- (-\beamr, \beamlen) -- (\beamr, \beamlen) -- (\beamr, 0);
  \draw[draw=black!75, fill=white] 
       (0, 0) ellipse ({\beamr} and 0.1);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (-2, -3) rectangle (2, 2);
\fill[black!5] (-2, -3) rectangle (2, 2);

\begin{scope}[yshift=-75]
\shadedraw[draw=black, left color=red!20, right color=red!90, rounded corners=1] 
   ({-0.5*\width},0) rectangle ({0.5*\width},1);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-50]
\shadedraw[draw=black, left color=gray!10, right color=gray!90] 
   ({-0.5*\width},0) rectangle ({0.5*\width},1);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-26]
\shadedraw[draw=black, left color=blue!20, right color=blue!60, rounded corners=4] 
   ({-0.5*\topwidth},0) -- ({0.5*\topwidth},0) -- ({0.5*\topwidth},\topheighta) -- ({0.5*\toptopwidth},\topheightb)
   -- ({-0.5*\toptopwidth}, \topheightb) -- (-0.5*\topwidth,\topheighta) -- cycle;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[rotate=10, xshift=-20]
\drawbeam
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[rotate=-10, xshift=20]
\drawbeam
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-26]
\shadedraw[draw=black, left color=blue!60, right color=blue!90, rounded corners=2]
   (-0.5*\midwidth,0) rectangle (0.5*\midwidth,\topheightb);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]